# combine variables in a vector/matrix

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, matrix, vector

I am a regular MATLAB user but new to c++. I would appreciate if one could help me solve the problem.

I have few variables and vectors. say

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
int main(){
int a=1; int b=1;
vector<int> V1(100,0);
vector<int> V2(100,0);

return 0;
}
```

I want to combine all variables (a,b,V1,V2) in a 2x101 matrix (say M) where the first and second rows of M are

```
M[0] = {a,V1};
M[1] = {V2,b};
```

how do I define M and assign the variables? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ability to insert in the front or at the back then you should use a `std::deque`. So you could do the following

```
deque<deque<int>> M;
M.push_back(V1);
M.push_front(a);
M.push_back(V2);
M[1].push_back(b);
```

This would create a 2 dimensional array or matrix with the two vectors as rows.

Or you could create a 2 dimensional vector and fill in the elements manually

```
vector<vector<int>> M;
M.resize(2);

// Reserve space for efficiency reasons, this prevents reallocation
M[0].reserve(V1.size() + 1);
M[0].push_back(a);
for (auto integer : V1) {
    M[0].push_back(integer);
}

M[1].reserve(V2.size() + 1);
for (auto integer : V2) {
    M[1].push_back(integer);
}
M[1].push_back(b);
```

Comment: but what about a and b?

Comment: My answer now should have what you wanted. Sorry about that! Please accept the answer if you think it is okay!